# Мозг или мозги?

Tags: множественное-число

Если говорим о мозге, он всегда "мозг", не "мозги". а если говорим о блюде (или будущем блюде), то говорим о "мозгах"?

почему?

Answer (score 3):

Существительное "мозг" имеет две формы числа, но в разных значениях слова может использоваться только одна форма (ед. или мн. числа).

1) **Единственное число**: Научная литература: Мозг как центральный отдел нервной системы человека и животных. Головной м. Спинной м. Также ум, сознание. Усталый м. не работал.

2) **Множественное число**: а) **разговорный стиль**:  мозгов нет, утечка мозгов за границу (переносный смысл), шевелить мозгами; б) **Кушанье,** приготовляемое из мозга некоторых домашних животных.  Жареные мозги. Говяжьи мозги.

Answer (score 0):

Он не всегда "мозг": в приниженном смысле применяются выражения "вышибить мозги" (напрочь разбить голову), "пораскинуть мозгами" (ирон. обдумать), "мозгов не хватает". Если мозг не рассматривается как анатомический орган или вместилище интеллекта (хотя бы как в совр. выражении "вынести мозг"), его уподобляют ленивым голубцам.